# How can you reference multiple rows in another table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Let's suppose I have a table of roles, for example,

```
Roles
-----
ID  Name
0   Salesman
1   Client
2   Manager
```

Let's also suppose that these roles are not mutually exclusive: that is, a person can be a salesman, a client, and a manager all at the same time.

If I have a `Person` table with a `Role` field, how am I able to reference multiple rows in the `Roles` table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You introduce a new table that references both of the original tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonRoles (
    PersonID int not null,
    RoleID int not null,
    constraint PK_PersonRoles PRIMARY KEY (PersonID,RoleID),
    constraint FK_PersonRoles_Persons FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) references Person (ID),
    constraint FK_PersonRoles_Roles FOREIGN KEY (RoleID) references Role (ID)
)
```

Assuming that the multiplicity is `m:n`, the above is correct. I made the assumption (not listed in your question) that more than one person can be e.g. a Salesman.

Comment: How do you reference a row in the `PersonRoles` table? There's no ID, since the primary key is composite. For example, how would you reference a PersonRole in some other table?

Comment: If you need to reference it from another table, then you have two choices - introduce a surrogate `ID` column, if that's all you're comfortable with, or include both `PersonID` and `RoleID` in the other table and use a composite foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another table having (at least) two columns:

```
PersonId, RoleId
```

So you can insert (e.g.)

```
1, 0
1, 2
2, 1
```

and your Person with id=1 will be a Salesman and a Manager, while Person with id=2 will be a Client.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you will need to make a "n-m relation". You need an extra table, eg. called "person_role", that contains foreign keys to both the other tables:

Person <===> PersonRole <===> Role

So you will have 3 tables:

```
Person
------------
ID
Name
etc.

Role
---------
ID
Name

PersonRole
------------
PersonID
RoleID
```

You also should make PersonID and RoleID into an unique composite key, to avoid any duplicates

/ Carsten