# Reference to multiple rows entity-framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How can I reference my column in table1 to multiple rows of another table in entity-framework work with custom navigation properties?

this problem can be solved in SQL with a temp table which is proposed in 
[How can you reference multiple rows in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794482/how-can-you-reference-multiple-rows-in-another-table)

Comment: perhaps provide us with a sample of your classes so we can help

Comment: I'm putting the link of example in my question. but If you want more explanation, I will prepare an example for you.

note that this is a known problem for use tag or role base table in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one row of a database table relates to several rows in another table of the same database, then we say that there is a one-to-many relation between those two tables.

For example: a table with Schools and a table with Students. Every School in the table of Schools has zero or more Students from the table of Students.

In a relational database a one-to-many relation is implemented by adding an extra column to the many table: a foreign key to the one table.

In the School-Student database, we would add a foreign key to the Student table, which would point to the School that this Student belongs to. So all Students of the School with primary key 4, would have the same value for the foreign key: 4

If you follow the [entity framework code first coding conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you would have something similar to:

```
class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}          // will become the primary key
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every School has zero or more Students (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}

class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}          // will become the primary key
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Student belongs to exactly one School, using foreign key:
    public int SchoolId {get; set;}
    public virtual School School {get; set;}
}
```

The DbContext:

```
class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to identify your tables, the columns of the tables and the relation between the tables. Only if you want to use different identifiers, or non-default behaviour, you'll need to add attributes or use fluent API.

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

People with a database background tend to think in SQL statements which they translate into LINQ. However, the use of the virtual properties simplifies the queries

> Give me the names of all Students together with the name of the school they attend.

```
var result = dbContext.Students.Join(dbContext.Schools, // join students and schools
    student => student.SchoolId,                        // from Student take the SchoolId,
    school => school.Id,                                // from School take the Id,
    (student, school) => new                            // when they match, make a new object
    {
        StudentName = student.Name,
        SchoolName = school.Name,
    });
```

Using the virtual properties makes life easier:

```
var result = dbContext.Students.Select(student => new
{
     StudentName = student.Name,
     SchoolName = student.School.Name,
});
```

In words: from the collection of Students, select from every Student his name and the name of his (one-and-only) School

Because I used the virtual properties, the code looks much simpler. Entity framework knows the relation between the tables and knows that an inner join is needed for this.

> Give me the names of all Schools with the names of their students

```
var schoolsWithTheirStudents = dbContext.Schools.Select(school => new
{
     Name = school.Name,
     StudentNames = school.Students.Select(student => student.Name).ToList(),
});
```

In words: from the collection of Schools, select from every School its names, and from every Student in this school his name.

> If you have a one-to-many in entity framework and you want to do an inner join, start with the many side (Students). If you want to do a GroupJoin, start with the one side (Schools)

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is complete is one to multiple relations. Looks like I've given you a lot of bad descriptions.
The problem is known as multiple to multiple relations in SQL which the solution in SQL was to use a temp table.

Comment: If your relation isn't a one-to-many, but a many-to-many, google for entity framework many-to-many. You'll find that both many sides have a `virtual ICollection<other many side>` This will internally create a junction table. Whenever you use the ICollection entity framework will use the junction table to perform the proper (group)join